# CFG and Automata regular language and dFA questions

Tags: automata, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, finite-automata

I have the following CFG questions which I am having a hard time getting my head around, I don't have any answers for them so I have no way of knowing if ive done them right or not (even though im pretty sure they're wrong) any help with reviewing my results would be much appreciated.

$P_1 =  (S \rightarrow 0S |1A|\epsilon, A \rightarrow 0A|1S)$

$P_2 = (S \rightarrow S1 |A0|\epsilon, A \rightarrow A1|S0)$

1.Show that the language $L(G_1)$ is regular.

A regular expression shows that the language is regular as far as I know.  Everytime I make derivatives of the CFG i just get variations of $010$ but I can see that it can finish with a 1 so my guess at the language is, $(0+1)(0|1)^*$.

2.Give strings of length 4 that belong to $L(G_1) \cap L(G_2)$

$L(G_2)$ is the complement of L(G_1) so the strings of length 4 accepted would be, $0000, 0101, 1001, 1010, 1100$

3.draw a dfa with at most 4 states for $L(G_1) \cap L(G_2)$

Considering the strings accepted the dfa diagram for this question will be the typical 4 state dfa that accepts even strings. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxihX.jpg

4.draw a dfa with at most 4 states for the complement $L(G_1) \cap L(G_2)$

This dfa diagram will be the same as the previous but with the non final states becoming final states and the final state becoming non final

Answer (score 1):

A derivation in $G_1$ can stop only when the production $S\to\epsilon$ is applied. This means that if the derivation ever uses $S\to 1A$, it must eventually use $A\to 1S$, so as to have an $S$ to delete. Here are some possible derivations:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
S&\Rightarrow^{n_1}&0^{n_1}S&\Rightarrow&0^{n_1}1A&\Rightarrow^{n_2}&0^{n_1}10^{n_2}A&\Rightarrow&0^{n_1}10^{n_2}1S&\Rightarrow^{n_3}&0^{n_1}10^{n_2}10^{n_3}S\\
\Downarrow&&\Downarrow&&&&&&\Downarrow&&\Downarrow\\
\epsilon&&0^{n_1}&&&&&&0^{n_1}10^{n_2}1&&0^{n_1}10^{n_2}10^{n_3}
\end{array}$$

Here $n_1,n_2$, and $n_3$ can be any non-negative integers, and a bit of thought should convince you that this diagram shows every possible derivation that uses the productions $S\to 1A$ and $A\to 1S$ just once each. Those derivations evidently suffice to generate all words of the forms $0^n$ for $n\ge 0$ and $0^{n_1}10^{n_2}10^{n_3}$ for $n_1,n_2,n_3\ge 0$. We can extend the derivation to the right by applying $S\to 1A$ again, then $A\to 0A$ some $n_4\ge 0$ times, then $A\to 1S$; if we then apply $S\to 0S$ some $n_5\ge 0$ times followed by $S\to\epsilon$, we’ve generated all words of the form $0^{n_1}10^{n_2}10^{n_3}10^{n_4}10^{n_5}$. If you continue this analysis, you should see that we can produce every word that contains an even number of $1$s. It’s not clear from the question whether you’re just supposed to identify the language, or whether you’re supposed to prove the correctness of your identification; the latter is substantially more difficult.

This language is regular, but it certainly isn’t represented by the regular expression $(0+1)(0\mid 1)^*$: that regular expression, which combines two different notations and should be written either $(0\mid 1)(0\mid 1)^*$ or $(0+1)(0+1)^*$, represents every non-empty word. In fact $L(G_1)$ is the regular language represented by the regular expression $(0^*10^*1)^*0^*$, among other possibilities. (Alternatively, you can demonstrate that it’s regular by designing a DFA that accepts precisely those words over $\{0,1\}$ that contain an even number of ones.)

$G_2$ does not generate the complement of $G_1$. For each $x\in\{0,1\}^*$ let $\overline x$ be the string that results from replacing each $0$ in $x$ by $1$ and each $1$ in $x$ by $0$. Let $x^R$ be the reversal of $x$. $G_2$ interchanges $0$ and $1$ and generates strings from right to left instead of from left to right, so $x\in L(G_0)$ if and only if $\overline x^R\in L(G_1)$. Now $\overline x^R\in L(G_1)$ if and only if $\overline x^R$ has an even number of ones, which is the case if and only if $\overline x$ has an even number of ones, which, finally, is the case if and only if $x$ has an even number of zeroes. Thus, $L_2(G)$ is the set of binary strings having an even number of zeroes, and $L_1(G)\cap L_2(G)$ is the set of binary strings having an even number of ones *and* an even number of zeroes. Thus, the set of words in $L(G_1)\cap L(G_2)$ of length $4$ is

$$\{0000,0011,0101,0110,1001,1010,1100,1111\}\;.$$

Your DFA for $L(G_1)\cap L(G_2)$ would be correct if you replaced the input labels $a$ and $b$ by the correct labels $0$ and $1$, and your answer to the fourth question is correct.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, just a question about notation for regular expression and language generated. are the symbols (), |, *, + restricted to use in just regular expressions or can they be used to express regular languages also ?

Comment: @dmnte: The symbols $\mid$ and $+$ both mean OR; some writers use one, and other writers use the other, but you don’t use both. (The symbols $\lor$ and $\cup$ are also sometimes used with this meaning.) Regular sets (or languages) can be represented similarly, but one usually uses the normal union symbol $\cup$; for instance, if $A$ and $B$ are sets of words, then $(A\cup B)^*$ is the set of all words that can be formed by concatenating members of $A\cup B$. If $A$ and $B$ are the languages of regular expressions $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then $(A\cup B)^*$ is the language of $(\alpha+\beta)^*$.